# Am I on the right track?

Tags: javascript

I am doing a javascript coding challenge where I must get references from the nav buttons from the HTML file. its for a registration form

HTML

```
<!-- Conditional Nav buttons -->
        <nav>
            <button class="users" id="users-tab-button">Register User</button>
            <button class="register" id="register-tab-button">View User List</button>
        </nav>
    <!-- /Conditional Nav buttons/ -->
```

JS

```
/* ----------------------------------------------------
    Setup
---------------------------------------------------- */

/* --- Tab References --- */

    // Get reference to all elements in register tab
    const registerTab = document.getElementsByClassName("register");
    console.log(registerTab);

    // Get reference to all elements in userList tab
    const userTabs = document.getElementsByClassName("users");
    console.log(userTabs);


/* --- Nav references --- */
//get refernce to Register User button
const regUser = document.querySelector('#users-tab-button');
console.log(regUser);

//get reference to viewUserList button
const viewUserList = document.querySelector("#register-tab-button")
console.log(viewUserList);
```

What I am doing here is getting the IDs of the nav buttons, but now, do I need to link them to the `registerTab` and the `userTabs`? as well, as it stands the `regUser` and the `viewUserList` are showing null

Comment: if your js appears before the body you have to wrap it inside the "DOMContentLoaded" event. Did you do this? Otherwise the js will execute before the HTML is fully rendered

Comment: Yes, my js does appear before the body however, I have it deferred. like this : ```<script src=./js/user-register.js defer></script>```does it still need the "DOMContentLoaded" event?

Comment: I believe so. If I recall correctly it executes after DOMInteractive but before DOMContentLoaded

Comment: I ran your code in the snippet tool here and both `regUser` and `viewUserList` were logged as elements as expected. What are you using to log the values? Regarding 'linking' them to other elements, since ids are unique, the references you have are unambiguous so I don't know why you might want to do that.